# Extra White Space In Table Cell When Inserting a DropDown

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, html-select

I'm having an issue where adding a select inside of a cell in my table is mysteriously just adding a bunch of extra space. I've been trying to research a solution but I cant find anything that addresses this particular issue I'm running into. Please help if you can.

```css
.datagrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.datagrid {
  font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #FA940F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.datagrid table td,
.datagrid table th {
  padding: 4px 4px;
}
.datagrid table thead th {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #FA921B), color-stop(1, #FF3526));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FA921B 5%, #FF3526 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FA921B', endColorstr='#FF3526');
  background-color: #FA921B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 1px solid #F2C530;
}
.datagrid table thead th:first-child {
  border: none;
}
.datagrid table tbody td {
  color: #000305;
  border-left: 1px solid #F2791D;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.datagrid table tbody .alt td {
  background: #FFDBA6;
  color: #090F07;
}
.datagrid table tbody td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="datagrid">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <select name="action" style="WIDTH: 160px; HEIGHT: 20px" type="text" padding="0">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
            <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alt">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alt">
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: Spacing Problem After Select]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to add `table-layout: fixed` to the `table` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6t5sq4k/)

```
.datagrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

> [**MDN - `table-layout: fixed`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):
>
> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. Any cell that has content that overflows uses the overflow property to determine whether to clip the overflow content.

Updated Code Snippet:

```css
.datagrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.datagrid {
  font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #FA940F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.datagrid table td,
.datagrid table th {
  padding: 4px 4px;
}
.datagrid table thead th {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #FA921B), color-stop(1, #FF3526));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FA921B 5%, #FF3526 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FA921B', endColorstr='#FF3526');
  background-color: #FA921B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 1px solid #F2C530;
}
.datagrid table thead th:first-child {
  border: none;
}
.datagrid table tbody td {
  color: #000305;
  border-left: 1px solid #F2791D;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.datagrid table tbody .alt td {
  background: #FFDBA6;
  color: #090F07;
}
.datagrid table tbody td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.datagrid table td.no-padding { padding: 0; }
.remove-whitespace { width: 154px; }
```

```html
<div class="datagrid">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="remove-whitespace">Action</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" class="no-padding">
          <select name="action" style="WIDTH: 160px; HEIGHT: 20px" type="text" padding="0">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
            <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alt">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alt">
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand @AggieEngr correctly, this doesn't solve the problem. `table-layout:fixed` only affects the cell width—not the cell height. In the screenshot, the first row is slightly higher which I believe is the issue @AggieEngr describing.

Comment: Thanks that really helped reduce the amount of space. However, there's still quite a bit and I was hoping to reduce it to so there's little to none. Do you have any suggestions for how this can be accomplished. @Josh Crozier

Comment: @aaronk6 Sorry for the ambiguity, but Im mainly trying to reduce the extra space that the select added until the next column. Sorry for the confusion once again

Comment: @AggieEngr You do have `padding` on the `td` element. Are you trying to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m6t5sq4k/ ?